# How can I define a field with a range of data in mongoose schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My current Mongoose Schema is this:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const resultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    scores: { type: Number, required: true },
    analysis: { type: String, required: true }
},
    { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Result', resultSchema);
```

And I want that scores field has a range of numbers. For example 100 to 500.

What should I do?

---

Meanwhile, Can I use MongoDB operator in Mongoose?

Answer (score 7):

Mongoose has several built-in validators to satisfy exactly this use case.

Since `scores` is of type `Number`, you can use the `min` and `max` validators to validate a range in this manner:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const resultSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    scores: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 100,
        max: 500
    },
    analysis: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true, toJSON: { virtuals: true } });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Result', resultSchema);
```

You can read about validation in Mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. And if I want to get the min and max of users what should I do?

Comment: Note that I dont want to define a period of appropriate number in field. I want to define a range of number in field. I mean I want that scores field be equals by 20 to 100. Actually I think scores should be an array.